# switch between tabs in tabhost

Tags: android, tabs, android-tabhost

i know there is a lot of previous questions here about that but i kinda lost...

this is my tabhost activity code:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class ManagerActivity extends ActivityGroup implements OnTabChangeListener {


private TabHost th;

private Intent Tab1Intent;
private Intent Tab2Intent;
private Intent Tab3Intent;
private Intent Tab4Intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.manager);

    th = (TabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    th.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());
    InitTabs(th);
    th.setOnTabChangedListener(this);

}

private void InitTabs(TabHost th){

    TabSpec specs = th.newTabSpec("tag1");
    specs.setIndicator("עדכון הודעות");
    Tab1Intent= new Intent(this, UpdateMessagesActivity.class);
    specs.setContent(Tab1Intent);
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag2");
    specs.setIndicator("עדכון אירועים");
    Tab2Intent = new Intent(this, UpdateEventsActivity.class);
    specs.setContent(Tab1Intent);
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag3");
    specs.setIndicator("עדכון זמני השבת");
    Tab3Intent = new Intent(this, updateShabathTimesActivity.class);
    specs.setContent(Tab1Intent);
    th.addTab(specs);
    specs = th.newTabSpec("tag4");
    specs.setIndicator("עדכון זמני יום חול");
    Tab4Intent = new Intent(this, UpdateDaysTimesActivity.class);
    specs.setContent(Tab1Intent);
    th.addTab(specs);

    th.setCurrentTab(0);

}

@Override
public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(tabId.equals("tag1")){
        // now what??
    }else if(tabId.equals("tag2")){
        // now what??
    }else if(tabId.equals("tag3")){
        // now what??
    }else{
        // now what??
    }

}
```

}

as u can see, i really don't know what to do in the OnTabChanged method...
i need a good explanation (with example) about that please.

thanks y'all.

Comment: Why are you using thigs which are deprecated now

Comment: i don't know man...cuz thats solve another problem, i can't find a normal and complete explanation about al that tabs thing...